# Python 2 - How do I use 'or'?

Tags: python

I'm really new to python, and I've just made a small program. If you type in "Hello" or "hello", and it will say "working", if you type in anything else it will say "not working". Here's the code I have so far:

```
print "Type in 'Hello'"
typed = raw_input("> ")
if (typed) == "Hello" or "hello":
   print "Working"
else:
    print "not working"
```

The code isn't working, no matter what I submit it will always say "Working", even if I type "jsdfhsdkfsdhjk". It does work if I take out the "or" and "hello", but I would like to to check for both. How can I make the script work?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 13):

You are checking to see if `typed` is equal to `"Hello"` OR if `"hello"` as a *standalone* expression evaluates to true (which it does). You don't get to chain multiple values to check against an original variable. If you want to check if an expression is equal to different things, you have to repeat it:

```
if typed == 'Hello' or typed == 'hello':
```

Or, something like:

```
if typed in ['Hello', 'hello']: # check if typed exists in array
```

Or, something like this:

```
if typed.lower() == 'hello': # now this is case insensitive.
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (typed) == "Hello" or "hello":` should be `if typed == "Hello" or typed == "hello":`

The problem at the moment is that `or` should separate two questions. It can't be used to separate two answers for the same question (which is what I think your expecting it to do).

So python tries to interpret "hello" as a question, and casts it to a true / false value. It happens that "hello" casts to `true` (you can look up why). So your code really says "if something or TRUE", which is always `true`, so "working" is always outputted.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try converting `typed` to lowercase, so you only have to check for one thing. What if they typed "HELLO"?

```
typed = raw_input("> ")
if typed.lower() == "hello":
    print "Working"
else:
    print "not working"
```

Answer (score 2):

The expressions on either side of `or` (and `and`) are evaluated independently of each other. So, the expression on the right side doesn't share the '==' from the left side.

If you want to test against multiple possibilities, you can either do

```
typed == 'Hello' or typed == 'hello'
```

(as Hbcdev suggests), or use the `in` operator:

```
typed in ('Hello', 'hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways (Atleast)

```
print "Type in 'Hello'"
typed = raw_input("> ")
if typed == "Hello" or typed == "hello":
   print "Working"
else:
    print "not working"
```

Or use the `in`

```
print "Type in 'Hello'"
typed = raw_input("> ")
if typed in ("Hello","hello",):
   print "Working"
else:
    print "not working"
```