# Python 2 - How to make the script go to a specific line?

Tags: python

This is kind of an extension to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077577/python-2-how-do-i-use-or), but I was wondering if it is possible to make the script go back to a specific line, if an event happens.

```
print "Type in 'Hello'"
typed = raw_input("> ")
if typed.lower() in ['hello', 'hi']:
    print "Working"
else:
    print "not working"
```

On the last line, if 'else' happens, can you make it so it restarts from line 2 again? 
Any help will be very greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Read about loops, you should find information in any beginner resource.

Comment: Besides that, it's not clear what you want to know. Which last question are you referring to?

Comment: Use a loop.  [GOTO is often considered harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful).

Comment: @PeterStahl He asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077577/python-2-how-do-i-use-or an hour ago :)

Answer (score 6):

You could put your code in an endless loop that only exits if the right word is typed in:

```
print "Type in 'Hello'"
while True:
    typed = raw_input("> ")
    if typed.lower() in ['hello', 'hi']:
        print "Working"
        break
    else:
        print "not working"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can let the program lie in a loop till the correct input is given

```
while True: 
    print "Type in 'Hello'"
    typed = raw_input("> ")
    if typed.lower() in ['hello', 'hi']:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 ways to do it , one with while loop , and one with recursion
the two answer before mine solved your problem with while loop , so i'd solve yours with recursion

```
def Inp():
    print "Type in 'Hello'"
    typed = raw_input("> ")
    if typed.lower() in ['hello', 'hi']:
       print "Working"
    else:
      print "not working"
      Inp()
Inp()
```

at the end just call the function `Inp` and it will continue asking for entering the value you want